# Infinite loop searching C++ std::map

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, stl

I have the following method in C++ which checks the name at the map

```
map<string, bool> namesMap;

bool IsValidName(const char* name) {

    string currentName(name, 16);

    if (MapContains(namesMap, currentName))
        return namesMap[currentName];
    else
        namesMap[currentName] = false;

    return false;
}


template<class T, class K>
bool MapContains(const std::map<T, K>& targetMap, const T key) {

    return targetMap.find(key) != targetMap.end();

}
```

Calling IsValidName() sometimes causes to capture the thread into an infinite loop. I've got a memory dump which shows that the thread is stuck in MapContains() method and further at xtree which is internally used by std::map.

All the names at the application are 6-8 characters long. So there is a bug at the line:

```
string currentName(name, 16);
```

Which causes all the checked names to have length: 16 instead of the correct one. As a result currentName has correct data in the first 6-8 chars and garbage at the rest ones. So the map is filled with 16-characters long strings with undefined data inside each of them.

Could this garbage cause the infinite loop while searching the map?

Or any other ideas what can cause it?

**Update:**
As I've described above I know the problem with line:

```
string currentName(name, 16);
```

Just want to know how it causes map to have **undefined behaviour**

Comment: Not the solution, but `IsValidName` can be simplified to `string currentName = ....; return namesMap[currentName];`.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for the idea. I've already refactored it but very curious to find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Ah... no, that would create an element in the map if name wasn't there.

Comment: Undefined behavior. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @Jakob That is what the method currently does, in a rather verbose way.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has **undefined behavior**.

The line `string currentName(name, 16);` attempts to build of string of 16 characters from a `const char*` pointing to 6-8 characters only.

---

**Solution:**

Provide at least 16 characters, or simply call `string currentName(name);`

Comment: I was under the impression, that, as an exception, reading from an uninitialized char was *not* UB, only unspecified.

Comment: @sp2danny, not, it really is UB.